# Converting comma separated string into array for postgres in rails gives unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I have a text field in a form for adding tags to a category. I want the input to be a comma separated string like `some,test,tags` and have it save that as an array in posgresSQL. My tags column was created with `t.string "tags", array: true`.

In my controller I have

```
category_params[:tags].split(',')
@category = Category.create(category_params)
```

But when I enter `some,test,tags` it shows up in the database as `["ome", "test"]` What have I done wrong here?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: ["some","test","tags"]

Comment: Have you tested it without this `array: true`? It seems to me this is your problem. You have a common string field comma separated. I think you don't need this.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida this would save it as `"some,test,tags"` right? I would rather have it saved in the db as an array so I can loop over it without having to convert the string to an array every time.

Comment: But this is my point. You are saving as an array and then spliting it as a common string with `category_params[:tags].split(',')`. This is causing the error, I think.

Comment: You realize `category_params[:tags].split(',')` doesn't mutate the value right? Does `Category.create(category_params.merge(tags: params[:tags].split(',')))` work as expected?

Comment: @etdev That was the problem `Category.create(category_params.merge(tags: params[:tags].split(',')))` didn't work but I did something similar that did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with

```
tags = category_params[:tags].split(',')
Category.create(category_params.merge({tags:tags}))
```